# Unable to deploy Spring boot 2 application due to HikariPool Exception during pool initialization

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hikaricp

I am unable to deploy Spring boot 2 application, due to Hikari Pool Initialization exception.

The error log is

```
com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool - HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.
    java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:494)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:441)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:436)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.processError(T4CTTIfun.java:1061)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.processError(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:550)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:623)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:252)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.doOAUTH(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:499)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.doOAUTH(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:1279)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:663)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.connect(PhysicalConnection.java:688)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:39)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:691)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:117)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:123)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:365)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:194)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:460)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:534)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$eeb1ae86.invoke(<generated>)
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:746)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:136)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:124)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$bcc0d23a.getConnection(<generated>)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.fetchConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:151)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:115)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:78)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:324)
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.jdbc.DataSourceHealthIndicator.getProduct(DataSourceHealthIndicator.java:122)
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.jdbc.DataSourceHealthIndicator.doDataSourceHealthCheck(DataSourceHealthIndicator.java:109)
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.jdbc.DataSourceHealthIndicator.doHealthCheck(DataSourceHealthIndicator.java:104)
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.AbstractHealthIndicator.health(AbstractHealthIndicator.java:84)
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.CompositeHealthIndicator.health(CompositeHealthIndicator.java:68)
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointWebExtension.getHealth(HealthEndpointWebExtension.java:50)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:223)
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.invoke.reflect.ReflectiveOperationInvoker.invoke(ReflectiveOperationInvoker.java:76)
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.annotation.AbstractDiscoveredOperation.invoke(AbstractDiscoveredOperation.java:61)
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.servlet.AbstractWebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping$ServletWebOperationAdapter.handle(AbstractWebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping.java:243)
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.servlet.AbstractWebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping$OperationHandler.handle(AbstractWebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping.java:299)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:209)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:877)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:783)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:974)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:866)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:851)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:865)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1655)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.server.WebSocketUpgradeFilter.doFilter(WebSocketUpgradeFilter.java:215)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642)
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.web.trace.servlet.HttpTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpTraceFilter.java:90)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:66)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642)
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:155)
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:123)
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:108)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642)
        at com.paysafe.ss.logging.LoggerFilter.doFilterInternal(LoggerFilter.java:114)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642)
        at org.oneplatform.commons.framework.rest.exception.ExceptionHandlerFilter.doFilterInternal(ExceptionHandlerFilter.java:43)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642)
        at com.paysafe.ss.logging.correlation.InternalHeadersFilter.doFilterInternal(InternalHeadersFilter.java:75)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:533)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:146)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:257)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1595)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:255)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1317)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:203)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:473)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1564)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:201)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1219)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:144)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:531)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:352)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:260)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:281)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:102)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:118)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:762)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:680)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

The application is getting deployed

```
  **Sample Application**
    Local:      http://127.0.0.1:8284
    External:   http://172.18.103.16:8284
```

After getting deployed, its trying to initialize the Hikari Pool and failing with invalid username/password. I had provided the correct credentials and was able to connect to Oracle database with sql developer.

**application.yml**

```
info:
  app:
    name: ${spring.application.name}
    description:  '@application.description@'
    version: '@application.version@'
    group: '@application.group@'
    gitCurrentBranch: '@application.current.branch@'
    gitChangeSet: '@application.latest.revision@'
    buildDate: '@application.timestamp@'
    component: Oneplatform
    category: Samples
    restApi: true
    usingDatabase: true

security:
  basic:
    enabled: false

spring:
  cloud:
    netflix:
      metrics:
        enabled: false
  datasource:
    dataSourceClassName: oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource
    url: ${datasource.url:jdbc:oracle:thin:@<hostname>:<port>/orcl}
    username: ${datasource.username:username}
    password: ${datasource.password:password}
    connectionTimeout: ${datasource.connection.timeout:45000}
    maxLifetime: ${datasource.max.lifetime:28000000}
    maximumPoolSize: ${datasource.maximum.pool_size:5}
    cachePrepStmts: ${datasource.cache.prep.stmts:true}
    prepStmtCacheSize: ${datasource.prep.stmt.cache.size:250}
    prepStmtCacheSqlLimit: ${datasource.prep.stmt.cache.sql.limit:2048}
    useServerPrepStmts: ${datasource.use.server.prep.stms:true}
  jpa:
    database: ORACLE
    show-sql: true
    generate-ddl: false
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: none
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
        id:
          new_generator_mappings: true
        jadira:
          usertype:
            javaZone: UTC
            databaseZone: UTC        
  rabbitmq:
    addresses: localhost:5672
    username: oneplatform
    password: test1234
    virtual-host: localPlatform

  liquibase:
    contexts: ${deployment.environment.name}
    change-log: classpath:db/mpp/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml
    enabled: false

rest:
  correlationId:
    acceptPattern: (/v\d.*)|(/business-portal/v\d/.*)
  logger:
    acceptPattern: (/v\d.*)|(/business-portal/v\d/.*)    

deployment:
  environment:
    name: ${deployment.environment:local}

metrics:
  jmx.enabled: true
  spark:
    enabled: false
    host: localhost
    port: 9999
  graphite:
    enabled: false
    host: localhost
    port: 2003
    prefix: jhipster

cache:
  timeToLiveSeconds: 3600
  ehcache:
    maxBytesLocalHeap: 16M
```

Versions we are using:

```
springBootVersion = "2.0.4.RELEASE"
oracleDriver = "12.2.0.1"
```

I was able to connect to deploy my application locally, but not in the environment. Am I missing anything in the configuration.

Comment: Where are `datasource.username` and `datasource.password` defined?

Comment: For local deployment, I had defined in application.yml which is working fine. For the QA environment, I had defined the username in env property file as 'db.username.application' and password would be picked up from the vault

Comment: Given that it works in your local deployment but fails in QA, the problem is almost certainly environmental. It's not clear how you expect `datasource.username` to map to `db.username.application`. There may also be a problem with your vault setup but it's impossible to tell as this is the first time you've mentioned it

Answer (score 2):

As our colleague, Pooja Aggarwal has stated that reason is invalid credentials supplied to the data source.
However, since the chances are that you've double-checked the credentials, an additional reason can be that the property that contains username / password is not propagated to the data source. So in order to see (at least) username start the application with a special flag:

```
--logging.level.com.zaxxer.hikari=DEBUG
```

This will print on console hikari initialization information so that you'll see the username.

Another way is to debug of course.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by exception, your username and password is wrong. Check your credentials.

Comment: I had validated that, I was able to connect with the credentials provided through sql developer to the database

Answer (score 1):

There's another issue here beyond the credentials: Spring Boot 2.x changed their binding of property names.  No more camel case or underscores: everything is lower case with hyphens between words.  See [here](https://spring.io/blog/2018/03/28/property-binding-in-spring-boot-2-0).

Answer (score 0):

This got resolved. The cause is a missing configuration file which maps datasource.password to db.username.password and the returned value is null. Due to this its throwing invalid username-password combination